# Scaling text to fit in Famo.us Surface

Tags: javascript, performance, famo.us

Here's the surface

```
this.gymNameSurface = new Surface({
  size: [true, gymDetailItemHeight],
  classes: ["gym_name_details"],
  content: ['<div id="gym_name_details">',this.options.data.gymName.properties.gymName,'</div>'].join(''),
  properties: {
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    fontSize: "2em",
    lineHeight: '72px'
  }
})
```

In cases when the gym name is under a certain # of characters, '2em' is the perfect size. In instances when the gym name is over a certain # of characters, it's too large.

How do I dynamically resize the fontSize of the the text inside the surface if, say, I don't want the surface's width to be > window.innerWidth/2?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with plain js:

```
var fontsize = "2em"; // Less text - big font
if(this.options.data.gymName.properties.gymName.length > 32) {
    fontsize = "1.4em"; // More text - smaller font size
}
```

then on your surface properties:

```
properties: {
    ...
    fontSize: fontsize,
    ...
}
```

Comment: Commenting trustkr's answer below: You do not need jQuery to check element heights. You can get the width & height of an element with Famo.us via `mySurface.getSize(true)` - The true-argument means to get the real size of the element, instead of the value set in properties.

Answer (score 1):

You might not know how wide your text will be at first, and thus you won't know what font size to choose for your font, but you can calculate it *after* it exists in the DOM. Something like this:

```
gymNameSurface.on('deploy', function() {

    var surfaceWidth = $('#gymNameSurface').width(); // or get the surface width on Surface.prototype.commit from the context.
    var $myText = $('#text');
    var textWidth = $myText.width();
    var fontSize = 24; // randomly picked
    var ratio = surfaceWidth/textWidth;

    fontSize = fontSize*ratio;

    $myText.css({'font-size': fontSize+'em'}); //  or whatever unit you are using.
});
```

Tip on the [commit function of a Surface](https://github.com/Famous/famous/blob/1a02c8084587d80519ea4bd3b55649ab32ee2e65/src/core/Surface.js#L318): from the context you can predetermine the width of a surface before it's content (a DOM element) has even been deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to vtntimo, here's final code:

```
this.gymNameSliderFontSize = "1.9em"
if (this.options.data.gymName.properties.gymName.length > 22) {
  this.gymNameSliderFontSize = "1.1em"; // More text - smaller font size
} else if (this.options.data.gymName.properties.gymName.length > 21) {
  this.gymNameSliderFontSize = "1.2em";
} else if (this.options.data.gymName.properties.gymName.length > 20) {
  this.gymNameSliderFontSize = "1.3em";
} else if (this.options.data.gymName.properties.gymName.length > 19) {
  this.gymNameSliderFontSize = "1.4em";
} else if (this.options.data.gymName.properties.gymName.length > 18) {
  this.gymNameSliderFontSize = "1.5em";
} else if (this.options.data.gymName.properties.gymName.length > 17) {
  this.gymNameSliderFontSize = "1.6em";
} else if (this.options.data.gymName.properties.gymName.length > 16) {
  this.gymNameSliderFontSize = "1.7em";
} else if (this.options.data.gymName.properties.gymName.length > 15) {
  this.gymNameSliderFontSize = "1.9em";
}

this.gymNameSurface = new Surface({ 
  size: [true, gymDetailItemHeight],
  classes: ["gym_name_details"],
  content: ['<div id="gym_name_details">',this.options.data.gymName.properties.gymName,'</div>'].join(''),
  properties: {
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    fontSize: this.gymNameSliderFontSize,
    lineHeight: '72px', 
    letterSpacing: '1px'
  }
})
```

Comment: Downvoted for tree of `if`s. `var len = this.options.data.gymName.properties.gymName.length; var size = Math.max(1, 7 - (len - 16); if (size > 7) size = 9; this.gymNameSliderFontSize = "1."+size+"em";` works just as well (or an array, object w/keys, etc).